# How much w and b values are adjusted in every trial of functioning? Is there any effective number of networks?

Tags: deep-learning

I am having trouble with understanding deep learning.
I see that deep learning is basically about inductive process, and so the function must be adjusted enough until it hits the right target.
But I can not figure out how much those w and b values should be changed in each trials. Is there any rule for the adjustment?
If there is not, then is there any trick? like, some formulas those are normally used.

And, do more networks always perform better?
I understand that single layer can not hit as many target as multiple layer does, but I don't know if 3-layer is better than 2-layer.

Answer (score 0):

The changes of w and b are based on the gradient of them.

You can calculate the gradient by taking derivative from the error (depending on the loss function). As you decrease the gradient, the error also decreases.

The maximum change of your gradient is `gradient/gradient_magnitude * total_error/gradient_magnitude`.

When you increase or decrease your function by its unit gradient, the output will be increased or decreased about the magnitude of its gradient. For that reason, the maximum changes of w and b are `gradient*err/mag^2`.

However, changing gradients to their limits is not recommended because problem of local minimum could occur. Therefore, learning rate or dropout algorithms are usually implemented.

The method above is not the only way to adjust the factors. Genetic algorithm, RBM, or reinforced learning methods could be implemented to replace or help above method.